# No such module 'SwiftData'

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-data

I am trying to create a data model for an experiment project. However, I am unable to import SwiftData. I am using Swift 5.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class WeatherDataModel{
    var dayOfWeek: String
    var imageImage: String
    var temperature: Int
    
    init(dayOfWeek: String, imageImage: String, temperature: Int){
        self.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek
        self.imageImage = imageImage
        self.temperature = temperature
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftData is iOS17+, is that the case of your target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Xcode 15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes) and [SwiftData documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata). SwiftData was shipped with Xcode 15 and supported iOS 17 and above. So, you need to upgrade Xcode to at least 15.0 (15A240d).

Comment: To clarify, SwiftData requires iOS 17.0+ or macOS 14.0+ or tvOS 17.0+ or watchOS 10.0+ or visionOS 1.0+.